# How to create new project for Blazor Class Library? Dependencies Error

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, blazor

When I created new project with  Blazor Class Libray template.
I got error like this:[image]

So I did for dotnet restore, but it didn't work either.

I also tried package manager to install the component like: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web -Version 5.0.4. but it doesn't work also.
The error I got this is as follows:

[image]

Could any body help me to get out of it.

Thanks in advance.

Joon

Comment: Could you show your .csproj file contents. I suspect your not targeting net5.0

Comment: Thanks but I set target to net5.0. <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

Comment: The first line is `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">` ?

Comment: Yes the first line is like <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

Comment: I got same problem in making project of BlazorWebAssembly as well.

Comment: Same comment as @BrianParker - please post your .csproj file so we can see the full configuration.  I can see a reference to netcoreapp2.1 ???

Comment: Thanks to you all. I have removed deleted package sources in NugetPackage Manager and reinstalled SDK. Then the problem I had resolved. Thanks again.

Comment: @JoonwK.  Great, glad it was resolved.  Could you please close off the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To add an answer for this ticket to improve it.**

The issue is that your [nuget package sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources) have some invalid, non-existent package sources. And when VS restore packages, it will first check whether the enabled package sources are effective. If not, it will stop the restore process and make it fail. And that is the cause of your problem.

So you have to do these:

**1)** uncheck the invalid package source `C:\xxx\Amisys.BPModelLib\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1`

[image]

**Or** just remove the invalid package source

**2)** just make sure that you checked the nuget.org package source

[image]

If you do not have, you should add it manually.